# Read data first to decide where to .pipe()

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I need to read some of a stream's (TCP/`net.Socket`) data before knowing where it should be piped. But the data doesn't seem to be reaching the `endSocket`.

```
socket.on('data', data => {
  var endSocket = getEndSocket(data);
  stream
    .pipe(endSocket)
    .pipe(socket); // send response back
});
```

The following code does work, but I have a feeling I should be using `.pipe()` for simplicity.

```
socket.on('data', data => {
  var endSocket = getEndSocket(data);
  endSocket.write(data);
  endSocket.pipe(socket); // send response back
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with the rest of the data. If you add a pipe to socket and keep the data listener and you send more packages over the same socket every package will be replicated to all `endSocket`'s that are being piped to.

The pattern that suits your first example is if you want to have an initial packet which selects what endSocket to connect to. Then you should set up a two-way pipe, and disconnect the data listener on that packet. You also have to write the data that you already read, as pipe will not replay that to the endSocket.

If every package that comes in from the same sourcesocket should go to different endSockets your second example looks perfect.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused how long pipes live for. Should I be manually `.unpipe()` ing? What happens if `.pipe()` if called more than once for a writable socket?

In my case the original `socket` is intended to be kept open, serving as a proxy tunnel for requests targeted at different sockets. I imagine there's some overhead to using the `.on('data'` handler as opposed to just `pipe()`ing the raw stream?

Comment: The `.pipe()` lives for the lifetime of the socket. Multiple `.pipe()`'s will multiplex the data to the different endsockets. If you give multiple pipes to the same socket it will receive multiple copies of the data.